# Architecture issue x86_64 for c program in macOS Catalina

Tags: c++, macos-catalina

In a c program, compiling with gcc, I get

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___nested_MOD_nestrun", referenced from:
      _run in cc5pyzxR.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I have not found a good solution to this, even if there are messages with the same issue.

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question.  All we know, so far, is that there is an undefined symbol somewhere, and that doesn't tell us much.  Also, C or C++?  The title says one thing and the tag the other.

Comment: [Possibly helpful](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/PyMultiNest/issues/10)